# Examples of using ReactiveSearch with ecommerce sub categories

Tags: elasticsearch, reactivesearch

I'm really impressed with ReactiveSearch so far but I can't see any examples of using it with sub categories.

This example looks great for filters and categories where there are no sub categories:
https://opensource.appbase.io/reactivesearch/demos/producthunt/

Is there a way to drill down to sub categories when a category is clicked?

Thanks,
Phil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we don't support this out of the box currently. A previous version used to have a component for doing this, we called it NestedList / NestedMultiList, but it was limiting in some ways.

The preferred way to do this today is using [ReactiveComponent](https://opensource.appbase.io/reactive-manual/v3/advanced/reactivecomponent.html) and bringing your design component which supports nested list behavior. ReactiveComponent allows you to bind any UI component by decoupling the associated query to trigger. You can configure any query (it would be one or more term(s) queries with a must clause for the sub-category behavior) and have this behave just like any other ReactiveSearch component.

Comment: Thanks for this info Sidi. We didn't get around to trying it yet. After 15 months, is this still the recommended approach?

Comment: The above link no longer works. This seems to be the current version: https://opensource.appbase.io/reactive-manual/advanced/reactivecomponent.html